# how to shift window title name on ubuntu-gnome from middle to left side on ubuntu-gnome 14.04?

Tags: gnome, window

I recently installed ubuntu-gnome 14.04 LTS 32bit on my laptop. I see the title name of window is in the center/middle of title bar. it's look wired :( . in 12.04 we see the tittle name is naturally in the left side of title bar. so I want to change it like 12.04's gnome DE's title bar.

have look on the screenshot of a window on Ubuntu gnome 14.04 .

[image]

here you see the title name "System Setting" is in the center of the title bar.

I want to get it on the left side like previous ubuntu-gnome window.

Answer (score 1):

"Ffffffff, Old question" You thought. :)

Your question associate with your desktop Window Manager. 
e.g. In GNOME the WM is gnome-shell so you should find a way to change the title position in gnome-shell. As far as I know there is no extension,etc for that so you should edit gnome-shell config files (NOT recommended) for it. Fortunately in GNOME 3.26 tweaks provided a new setting that you can change the control buttons in window (hope they provide a new setting for change window title position in future). 
*Also if anyone know how to change the window title position in gnome-shell I'll glad to know how to change it.*